# Android studio no autoejecuta las aplicaciones

Tags: java, android, android-studio, git, git-merge

tengo un problema con android studio resulta que estoy trabajando una aplicacion con mi compañeros y estamos utilizando git para el control, pero luego de fusionar mi rama con otra android studio dejo de autoejecutar la aplicacion luego de instalarla... solo la instala y ahi queda...

no se si sera un problema durante el merge o algun fichero que cambios entre un equipo y otro

se agradece la ayuda

Comment: Podrían ser varios motivos. Un motivo prodría ser que los packages en los diferentes Activitys sean diferente y otro que la aplicación se este ejecutando en modo test y no permita ejecutarse.

Comment: y a tus compañeros sí les funciona?

Comment: Seguramente es un error de código al realizar el "merge", , en este caso revisa el código. al realizar preguntas recuerda revisar [ask], saludos!

Comment: Pues no creo que sea el package por que todos trabajamos sobre el mismo proyecto

Comment: No mis compañeros tienen el mismo problema

Comment: Peri el codigo como tal no creo que sea el problema sino un fichero de configuración pero no se cual.... Lo revisaré muchas gracias

Comment: Saludos, han intentado realizar estos comandos por consola? para hacerles seguimiento y saber que ha pasado? por consola primero podrían probar con un `git status`, posiblemente puedan ver el problema allí, por experiencia cuando hago `merge` o `push` lo hago desde la consola, por que a veces `AndroidStudio` da problemas con ese tipo de cosas y las soluciono por consola, no se si es el mejor método pero al menos es el que mejor me ha funcionado. @LandyCuadra

Answer (score 0):

Bueno al final encontre una solucion, probablemente el problema si fue durante el merge de la aplicacion, pero la solucion es tan basica como ir a run -> edit configurations, en esta ventana launch se habia seteado a nothing basta con ponerlo en default activity y listo... otro de mis compañeros lo soluciono actualizando el android studio, Gracias por su ayuda.